# How to use \autoref to create a page link?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am using the `hyperref` package and want to use the `\autoref{}` command to output the page of the referenced label (similar to `\pageref{}`). The label is not inside a figure, equation, etc., so by default `\autoref{}` creates a `section x.y` link, instead of a `page z` link that I would like.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I found it. There's a command named `\autopageref{}` which replaces `\pageref{}` and does exactly what I wanted. More info [here](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-130004).